# How can I define a Lua function with gopher-lua that has a pre-defined table as param, where the Lua script can access the table within that function?

Tags: go, lua

I know how to define a Go function and set it global (the Double example from the docs). But what, if the argument of this function should be a pre-defined table?

```lua
function calling_this_function_would_be_required(predefined_table)
  print(predefined_table["something"])
end
```

The IMAP server Dovecot does provide something like the above: https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/lua_based_authentication/#examples

And I would like to also provide pre-defined functions with a table (or even user data). But I really have no idea on how to achieve this.

Having a table set global is easy (L.SetGlobal(...)), but how do I add it to a expected function?

Adding some function in Go

```golang
func CallMe(L *lua.LState) {
    // How do I add a table as argument??
}

func Foo() {
    L := NewState()
    defer L.Close()

    t := L.NewTable()
    t.RawSetString("example", lua.LString("some_value"))

    // I do not want a global table. I would like an expected Lua function that has _this_ table as argument
    L.SetGlobal("predefined_table", t)

    // Not even sure with his...
    L.SetGlobal("calling_this_function_is_required", L.NewFunction©llMe)) 
}
```

If someone could enlight me a bit that would be great :-) Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking "how do I pass a table as an argument when calling a Lua function from Go?"

Comment: I am not 100% sure. When I started with Dovecot Lua, I found it really nice that there was expected a Lua function that had an object/table as argument. You as a Lua dev had to write this function and use this table. Now to my question: I would like to have this in my Go apps to. Expecting a Lua function that provides a table as arg and a user must use it. And I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @koyaanisqatsi answer, I found out how to get things working in Go.

Go code example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/yuin/gopher-lua"
)

type Person struct {
    Name       string
    GivenName  string
    Street     string
    PostalCode string
    City       string
}

func main() {
    p := &Person{
        Name:       "Mustermann",
        GivenName:  "Max",
        Street:     "Sackgasse 19",
        PostalCode: "36304",
        City:       "Alsfeld",
    }

    L := lua.NewState()
    defer L.Close()

    if err := L.DoFile("sample.lua"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    t := L.NewTable()
    t.RawSetString("name", lua.LString(p.Name))
    t.RawSetString("given_name", lua.LString(p.GivenName))
    t.RawSetString("street", lua.LString(p.Street))
    t.RawSetString("postal_code", lua.LString(p.PostalCode))
    t.RawSetString("city", lua.LString(p.City))

    if err := L.CallByParam(lua.P{
        Fn:      L.GetGlobal("call_me"),
        NRet:    1,
        Protect: true,
    }, t); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ret := L.Get(-1) // returned value
    L.Pop(1)         // remove received value

    fmt.Println("The result of the Lua function is:", ret)
}
```

sample.lua file:

```lua
function call_me(tbl)
    print(tbl.name)
    print(tbl.given_name)
    print(tbl.street)
    print(tbl.postal_code)
    print(tbl.city)

    return 0
end
```

Result:

```
Mustermann
Max
Sackgasse 19
36304
Alsfeld
The result of the Lua function is: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a predefined table if argument is ommited.
Example

```
-- pdtfunc.lua
local function pdtfunc(pdt)
  local pdt = pdt and setmetatable(pdt, {__index = table}) or setmetatable({"Exampe Value (Index Key 1)", ["Example"] = "Example Value by named Key"}, {__index = table})
  return(pdt)
end

return(pdtfunc)
```

The Constructor of the returned table has all table functions attached as methods.
Example of use (Lua 5.1 Standalone)

```
€ /bin/lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> pdt = require("pdtfunc")
> print(pdt())
table: 0x565b2bf0
> print(pdt():concat()) -- Attached Method to get string or number values
Exampe Value (Index Key 1)
> print(pdt()[1])
Exampe Value (Index Key 1)
> print(pdt()["Example"])
Example Value by named Key
> print(pdt().Example)
Example Value by named Key
> mytab = pdt()
> print(mytab:concat())
Exampe Value (Index Key 1)
> print(mytab.Example)
Example Value by named Key
> mytab:insert("New Value with insert()")
> print(#mytab)
2
> print(mytab:concat("\n"))
Exampe Value (Index Key 1)
New Value with insert()
> -- Now give a table as argument
> mytab = require("pdtfunc")({"With a table as argument"})
> print(mytab:concat())
With a table as argument
```